# Can anyone help identify this uniform jacket?

Tags: identification, uniform

[image: uniform jacket]

I believe that it is a replica, but I do not know what of?
Does anyone know the nation and time period it is

[image: button with symbol]

[image: label in foreign language]

Comment: An image of one of the buttons, which seems to contain a symbol, would be helpfull. The collar looks familiar, but without further details may be hard to determine. Look also if  somewhere inside the uniform if any written lable exists which should also be shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The label says "**Factory Hr**[isto] **Botev"** [in town] **Kalofer**". Hristo Botev is Bulgarian national hero from the town of Kalofer (so it is logical that factory named it after him), so this uniform is most likely Bulgarian [unless Bulgaria made uniforms for other countries]. The general look of it and the use of a five-pointed star points to the socialist period. Thus, it is most likely a replica of a uniform from socialist Bulgaria (1945-1990).